# this is sentence correct and portray what i mean to say

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

**you sitting behind me was less distracting that you came and sat in front of me**
is this grammatically correct, does this sentence portray what i mean to say if you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're incorrectly using "that" instead of "than" and you're mixing a gerund (sitting) used as a noun with past-tense verbs. You could phrase it like this:

> When you sat behind me, I was less distracted than when you came and sat in front of me.

You could also use three gerunds, which would be grammatical, but I find this phrasing more awkward:

> Your sitting behind me was less distracting than your coming and sitting in front of me.